# Scala : How to split words using multiple delimeters

Tags: scala, split

Suppose I have the text file like this:

```
Apple#mango&banana@grapes
```

The data needs to be split on multiple delimiters before performing the word count.

How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `split` method:

```
scala> "Apple#mango&banana@grapes".split("[#&@]")
res0: Array[String] = Array(Apple, mango, banana, grapes)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to count words, you don't need to split. Something like this will do:

```
  val numWords = """\b\w""".r.findAllIn(string).length
```

This is a regex that matches start of a word (`\b` is a (zero-length) word boundary, `\w` is any "word" character (letter, number or underscore), so you get all the matches in your string, and then just check how many there are.

If you are looking to count each word separately, and do it across multiple lines, then, `split` is, probably, a better option:

```
    source
      .getLines
      .flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
      .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
      .groupBy(identity)
      .mapValues(_.size)
```