# How to split a data with different delimiter in single RDD in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

WARN:router1 warning in Japan.
How to do the splitting of the above line by delimiter ":" and " " in single RDD and how to create Dataframe after creating RDD with below info
WARN router1 JApan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala : How to split words using multiple delimeters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758378/scala-how-to-split-words-using-multiple-delimeters)

Answer (score 1):

First split the string via Regex and create the RDD as RDD[String]. To create the dataframe you need to include its schema although because RDD is a RDD[String] you can create the Dataset directly and then transform to DataFrame:

```
import spark.implicits._

val str = "WARN:router1 warning in Japan"
val arr = str.split("(:|\\s)")

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(arr)
val ds = spark.createDataset(rdd)

ds.toDF().show()
```

gives

```
+-------+
|  value|
+-------+
|   WARN|
|router1|
|warning|
|     in|
|  Japan|
+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val data = Seq("WARN:router1 warning in Japan")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data) // RDD of Strings
import spark.implicits._
val dataDF = rdd
             .flatMap(line => line.replace(":"," ").split(" "))
             .toDF("value") // Dataframe

dataDF.show()
```

output

```
+-------+
|  value|
+-------+
|   WARN|
|router1|
|warning|
|     in|
|  Japan|
+-------+
```